# How to avoid NullPointerException when deleting a document in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to give the user in my app the possibility to delete his account so when he clicks on the delete button a document gets deleted which contains all his informations. The name of the document is his displayName so I get this as a string but when I run the code you are seeing below I get a NullpointerException in this line:
 `String currentUsername = user.getDisplayName();`
even though the displayName is not null.

**Edit:**

I found the solution on my own, see the answer below.

Here is my method:

```
btn_delete_account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                user.delete()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    deleteDocument();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

...

public void deleteDocument (){

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String currentUsername = user.getDisplayName();

        db.collection("User").document(currentUsername)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                        Toast.makeText(PersonalSettings.this, "Your account was successfully deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(PersonalSettings.this, SignInActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: If the exception is from that line, “user” is likely null. The returned string display name value is assigned on that line, without any chance for itself to trigger a NPE.

Comment: I added the button listener where I use my delete method in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error:

I called my delete method after I used the user.delete() method which deletes the signed in user, so logically the displayName was also deleted.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you have to **check that current user is not null**

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(user==null)
{
 return;
}
```

if current user is not null then get its name and **further check that it's name is not null.**

```
String currentUsername = user.getDisplayName();
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(currentUsername))
 {
  return;
 }
```

> if name is not null then go for delete document as follows :

```
public void deleteDocument (){

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     if(user==null)
     {
      return;
     }

    String currentUsername = user.getDisplayName();
     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(currentUsername))
     {
        return;
     }

    db.collection("User").document(currentUsername)
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                    Toast.makeText(PersonalSettings.this, "Dein Account wurde erfolgreich gelöscht.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(PersonalSettings.this, SignInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the error.  It's saying that `user` is null, not the display name.  This means there is currently no user signed into the app.  You will have to write some code to check for this case.

I also strongly suggest not using a display name as the ID for a document in Cloud Firestore.  Since you're using Firebase Authentication, the user already has a [unique ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getUid()) assigned to their account.  This is the preferred way to store per-user data.

Comment: When I point my mouse over ```.getDisplayName();``` it says "Method invocation `getDisplayName`may produce NullPointerException. I am using the displayName as name because I thought it would then be easier to search a player in a SearchView or check if a username already exists

Comment: Please read my answer again.  The NullPointerException error is telling you that `user` is null.  The code hasn't even progressed to getting the display name yet.